# Get property of list element in C#

Tags: c#, list, oop

I have a class like that:

```
public class A{
 //some properties
}

public class B : A{
   //some more properties
}

public class C : A{
   //some more properties
}
```

I would like to make a list of B, C and so on like that:

```
List<A> mylist = new List<A>()
mylist.add((B)someobject);
mylist.add((C)someobject);
```

If I add B, C etc. type of elements to mylist, It will cast them to type A. Therefore if I want to get properties of mylist[0] it gives me only class A properties.

How can I solve the problem and reach B or C type properties too?

Comment: By casting them back to the actual type, you can use the `is`-operator to check the type first

Comment: But i don't know the original tpye of the object when I iterate through the list.

Comment: As mentioned, use: `foreach(A a in mylist{ if(a is B){B b = (B)a;}else if(a is C{C c = (C)a;}) })`

Comment: That's why you use the `is` keyword to find out, i.e. `if (item is B) ...`

Comment: Thanks. That is not the prettiest way, but it works!